# Setting up a github repository

Tags: git, github, repository

please how can i create a github repository that goes in the format https://github.com/me50/patrick001.git I am new to github. The patrick001 in the repository name is supposed to be my github username; each time i want to create the repository, it takes the format https://github.com/patrick001/me50 (as me50 will now be the repository name created in my git account). [This is how the interface looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr0ed.jpg) This has caused a delay for a while now; any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What problem do want to solve with changed URL?

Answer (score 0):

In GitHub the url format is like

```
github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```

Like [profile](https://github.com/HYAR7E)
and [repository](https://github.com/HYAR7E/CauchyMachine)

Comment: If possible, how do i change the url format to suit what i'm looking for?

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible

Comment: Does it mean this format https://github.com/me50/patrick001.git is not possible?